# IconButton with Row

Tags: flutter, dart, row, iconbutton

I would like, in this code, to put the IconButton in the top right corner of each ItemView. The ItemDescription and the ItemTitle centered at the top. I try to put them in the same Row but I can't get them to fit together, either the IconButton sticks to the text or it's in the middle.
I think it is easy but I didn't find a solution.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import '../recyclerview/data.dart';
import 'package:watch/constants.dart';


class ListViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override 
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new ListViewExampleState(
    );
  }
}

class ListViewExampleState extends State<ListViewExample>{
  List<Container> _buildListItemsFromItems(){
    int index = 0;
    return item.map((item){

      var container = Container(
        decoration: index % 2 == 0?
        new BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF)):
          new BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0xFFFAFAF5)
          ),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: new CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: item.imageURL,
                width: 200.0,
                height: 100.0,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 75.0 ),
                          child: Text(
                             item.title,
                            style: kItemTitle,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                          child:Text(
                            item.description,
                            style: kItemDescription,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                  ),
                  new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.black,),
                          iconSize: 24.0,
                          onPressed: null
                        ),
                      )
                  ],)
              ]),
            ),
          ]),
      );
      index = index + 1;
      return container;
    }).toList();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('Accueil', style: kAppBarStyle,),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,  
          elevation: 0,
       ),
       body: ListView(
      children: _buildListItemsFromItems(),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update** : I have added a `Spacer()` and put all in the same row, and set CrossAxisAlignment to .center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the Icon in the same row as the title and the description, with a [Spacer()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) in between. That will then give you an overflow error, because the Spacer wants to take up as much space as physically possible, so with no restriction it goes on to infinity. To tell the Spacer that it is only allowed a finite amount of space, you have to set the mainAxisSize of the row to MainAxisSize.min

Here's the code, with a couple alterations so I was able to run it for myself.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ListViewExample(),
    );
  }
}

class ListViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new ListViewExampleState();
  }
}

class ListViewExampleState extends State<ListViewExample> {
  var items = [
    Item(),
    Item(),
    Item(),
    Item(),
  ];
  List<Container> _buildListItemsFromItems() {
    int index = 0;
    return items.map(
      (item) {
        var container = Container(
          decoration: index % 2 == 0
              ? new BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF))
              : new BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0xFFFAFAF5)),
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                margin: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: new Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 150.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 75.0),
                      child: Text(
                        item.title,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                      child: Text(
                        item.description,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite_border,
                        size: 14,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      onTap: null,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
        index = index + 1;
        return container;
      },
    ).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Accueil'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: _buildListItemsFromItems(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  final String title;
  final String description;

  Item({this.title = 'FooTitle', this.description = 'BarDescription'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks @spencer but the text is on the left and I want to put it in the center. How can I do that ?

Comment: Are you talking about the description text or what are you referring to?

Comment: It is the text of the title and the text of the description which I want to put in the center of the row.  Thanks

Comment: Set the crossAxisAlignment property of the row to CrossAxisAlignment.center (I don't know exactly what you're describing so if that isn't what you want I'll need to see a picture)